# How to open a class that extends ListFragment on click of navigation drawer item?

Tags: android

In this function on click of nav_manage I want to open ViewTasks that extends ListFragment. Can someone please suggest some code example? 
This is a function in my MainActivity.

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    displaySelectedScreen(item.getItemId());
return true;
}



  private void displaySelectedScreen(int itemId)
{
    Fragment fragment = null;
    //initializing the fragment object which is selected
    switch (itemId) {
        case R.id.nav_send:
            fragment = new Invitation();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_camera:
            fragment=new Home();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_manage:
            fragment=new ViewTasks();
            break;
        default:
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity2.this,"Choose Something",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    //replacing the fragment
    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
        ft.commit();
    }
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
}
```

My ViewTasks class:

```
public class ViewTasks extends ListFragment {
private Button addButton;
private TaskManagerApplication app;
private TaskListAdapter adapter;
private Button removeButton;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_fragment, container, false);

}
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    //you can set the title for your toolbar here for different fragments different titles
    getActivity().setTitle("Task Scheduler");
    app = (TaskManagerApplication)getActivity().getApplication();
    adapter = new TaskListAdapter(this.getActivity(), app.getCurrentTasks());
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    setUpViews();

}
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    adapter.forceReload();
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    adapter.toggleTaskCompleteAtPosition(position);
    Task t = adapter.getItem(position);
    app.saveTask(t);
}

protected void removeCompletedTasks() {
    Long[] ids = adapter.removeCompletedTasks();
    app.deleteTasks(ids);
}

private void setUpViews() {
    addButton = (Button)getView().findViewById(R.id.add_button);
    removeButton = (Button)getView().findViewById(R.id.remove_button);

    addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            getFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.content_frame, new AddTaskActivity())
                    .commit();
        }
    });
    removeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            removeCompletedTasks();
        }
    });

}
```

}

I want this function to open the ViewTasks fragment which has listview of tasks scheduled.
When I follow the same pattern as my above case it shows this error:

Incompatible types:

Required: android.app.Fragment

Found: com.happy.taskmanager.ViewTasks

Comment: Why is your class named ViewTasks**Activity** when it extends List**Fragment**?

Comment: Please include the class which contains your code example. I also suggest you learn about how to show fragments dynamically with FragmentManager.

Comment: Sorry for that, Its ViewTasks.class

Comment: What is the rest of `displaySelectedScreen()`? It appears that you did not paste it all here.

Comment: To answer your question, you should just follow the pattern already shown in your other `case`s.

Comment: when I follow the similar pattern as in my other case it shows incompatible types.

Comment: Please show the exact code you are using and the entire error message. Also be sure to read all of my previous comments and edit your question with the requested information. Additionally, please show the `ViewTasks` class. For now, all we need is the body: `public class ViewTasks extends ??? { ... }`. The `???` is the part that I don't know and is important in helping you further.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I have attached my ViewTasks class code and explained the error which I am getting. Please see to it.

Comment: **`displaySelectedScreen()`** looks incomplete. Is this what you need help with in particular? Fragments have A LOT of overhead, you should take **Code-Apprentice**'s advice.

Comment: @SamusArin...I have edited and shown the complete code of my displaySelectedScreen().  The problem is at ViewTasks case where it shows error as incompatible types.